# Part of string before a colon and then the part after the colon using a scanner

Tags: java, regex, string, hashmap, java.util.scanner

Like the title says is it possible to read part of a String before a colon and then the rest of the String after the colon using a scanner?

If you have a String:

```
"AA:BigHouseOnTheBeach"
```

is it possible for me to store the first part `"AA"` in a separate String and `"BigHouseOnTheBeach"` in a second separate String?

Here's my code:

```
public NumberPlates() {
    // opg 2a) initialiser districtMap
    districtMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    readFile();
}

public void readFile() {
    file = new File("src/opg2_numberplates/Nummerplader.txt");

    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

        if (reader.hasNext()) {
            kb = reader.next();
            pk = reader.next();
            districtMap.put(kb, pk);
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("Null pointer");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}
```

At the moment, it puts `"AA:BigHouseOnTheBeach"` and `"AB:SmallHouseOnTheBeach"` into my map as key and value. I want to put `"AA"` as key and `"BigHouseOnTheBeach"` as value.

Comment: How does `Scanner` decide what separator to use? What does the javadoc say?

Comment: Are you hinting at delimiter?

Comment: That's right. Just set the right delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setDelimiter(String regex)` method of `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("Hello: There!");
scan.useDelimiter(":");
System.out.println(scan.next());
System.out.println(scan.next());
```

Output:

> "Hello"
>   " There!"

If you don't want the second string to include the space after the `":"`, change to:

```
scan.useDelimiter(":\\s*");
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, how ever it now outputs

"AA"
"BigHouseOnTheBeach"
"AB"
--
Can i sort of close it to only grab the word before ":" and after?

Comment: What is separating `"AA:BigHouse..."` from `"AB:SmallHouse..."`? Are they on different lines?

Comment: So you can replace the `regex` by `":\\s*|\n"`, which tells the `Scanner` to skip `":"` OR `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use String split method to split the string based on the delimiter. Following is the code.

```
if (reader.hasNext()) {
        String input = reader.next();
        String[] parts = input.split(":");
        kb = parts[0];
        pk = parts[1];
        districtMap.put(kb, pk);
    }
```